# How can I change the look of a post as is displayed

Tags: posts, templates

When an article is posted it comes out like this:
Where the title is on top, then the picture, then the image.

[image]

But what I would like to do is how technobuffalo.com has it:

[image]

How is this done? is a template html copied and pasted for each new article and displays in that format or does WordPress render it for each posting?

Thanks

Comment: The look of the post-details, depends on the theme you are using. And it's obviously a bigger matter of CSS, compared to HTML. I guess you are using your own custom theme. For us, from a distant perspective, it'd be better if you post your `index.php`, `functions.php` codes for us. You can use [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) for pasting the bigger codes. :)

Comment: im not using any template, its a fresh installation of wordpress.

Comment: Then please confirm that, you are using the default theme TwentyTwelve.

Comment: i am using the theme named Alexandria by ThemeAlley.com but i'll still understand what to do if you explain it using twentytwelve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TwentyTwelve index.php:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

the line in the middle is loading the `content.php` to show the posts on the homepage.

a. In `content.php`, `the_post_thumbnail()` in *line 18* is responsible for the image, specifically the Featured Image, of a post.

b. And this portion is responsible for the Title of the post:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
```

c. The content or excerpt is responsible for the details of the post:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
```

d. And the whole `<footer class="entry-meta"> ... </footer>` is responsible for the author information and post information etc.

And the code-blocks are conditional specific to different pages, like:

- `is_single()` - Detail of a Post
- `is_archive()` - Archive of posts, can also refer to day-month-year archives
- `is_home()` - Index of the site
- `is_front_page()` - If you have any front-page.php
- `is_page()` - The detail page of any page content
- `is_search()` - For search result page

---

Now,
Specific to your problem, just make a new page called `content-custom.php` with:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <div class="post-image">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div> <!-- .post-image -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="post-details">
        <div class="post-meta">
            <?php // Thanks to Ian Stewart for the bit of codes below ?>
            <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'your-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
            <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
            <span class="entry-date"><abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO') ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></abbr></span>
        </div> <!-- .post-meta -->
        <div class="post-text">
            <?php // For a simple exceprt of the body content ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div> <!-- .post-text -->
    </div> <!-- .post-details -->

</article><!-- #post -->
```

And you have to add a simple float to the image div in your `style.css`:

```
.post-image{ float: left; }
```

Now, in your `index.php`, instead of loading any custom template, load your custom content page using the following code within your [WordPress loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'custom' ); ?>
```

Comment: thank you so much, you have thought me how to customize a posts page. Thank you so much for that. Now all i have to do is setup the css.

Comment: Mention not please. :)

Answer (score -2):

Look into your archive.php and single.php files in your template. Then modify the html output of those files, and also fix css related to those items.

Comment: I'm afraid, the question is not specific to archive or detail of a post. The technobuffalow screenshot is clearly showing a home page-display of the post, so it means the `index.php`.